# Weights to the fields in flutter

Tags: flutter

In Android studio we give the height or width zero and give it some weight. Is there any way we can do this in flutter ? if Yes then how ?

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etInputOTP1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>          //Like this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Expanded widget to give a child widget a specific weight when laying out a row or column.

To give a widget a weight of 2 in a row:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text('Widget 1'),
      flex: 2,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text('Widget 2'),
      flex: 1,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: So here flex is similar to Weight in Android Studio, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! The flex property of Flexible works in a similar way to the "weight" attribute in Android's LinearLayout.

In Flutter, the flex property determines how much of the remaining free space in the main axis a widget should take up.